# Convert dictionary to coo_matrix

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a dictionary like this,

```
{(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0): 0, (19, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0): 12, (85, 1, 87, 0, 0, 0): 22, (78, 79, 80, 81, 0, 0): 20, (0, 17, 18, 19, 0, 0): 8, (24, 25, 26, 27, 0, 0): 6, (62, 63, 64, 65, 0, 0): 16}
```

How do I convert this to a coo_matrix? I tried the following but I get `Error: int object is not subscriptable`

```
data,row, col = [], [], []
 for k, v in diction.items():
     r = int(k[0][1:])
     c = int(k[1][1:])
     data.append(v)
     row.append(r-1)
     col.append(c-1)
     # Create the COO-matrix
 coo = coo_matrix((data,(row,col)))
```

I need to do this because the LightFM.fit method only takes in coo matricies as argument.

**Expected output (coo matrix)**:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0)      0
(19, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0)    12
(85, 1, 87, 0, 0, 0)    22
```

Comment: What is the expected output of this?

Comment: @RoadRunner Pls see edit

Comment: As stated this does not make sense (given a ML task). Be more precise about potential binary-encoding and v being a target in your ML task (not part of that matrix)! If it's unclear what the problem is or what i'm asking for: make sure you understand what scipy's coo_matrix is. It's always 2d (of course one dimension can be of a single dim to describe a vector) and holds numerical values (indexed by two dimensions).

Comment: @sascha The LightFM's fit method needs the argument to be a np.float32 coo_matrix of shape [n_users, n_items]) – the matrix containing user-item interactions. So how do I convert the dictionary into that?

Comment: I know (or expect) what they want. But you seem to be new to ML and should grab those basic data-formats first before asking things like that. Try to bring your expected output into MATRIX-form. That's all coo_matrix can give you. If your expected output is not a matrix (2-d!) like your expected output, there is no way you can do this. You are probably asking for one_hot_encoding or some other preprocessings. But that has not much to do with scipy's sparse-matrices.The format is quite standard,you will learn a lot from scikit-learn's documentation. Visit it and read the preprocessing tutorial.

Comment: And as your item-user aka matrix-factorization model is a bit special, things get simpler (compared to my comment above). But the mapping from what you presented and this model, well... i don't see it. A sparse-representation of those matrices is usually something with 3 values; item-user-value. Now compare that with your's (way too many dimensions). And make sure you know the difference between a matrix and a tensor! There is not much (working) software for (low-rank) tensor-factorization.

Comment: This isn't going to work.  It looks like you want a 6d array.  The scipy sparse package only creates 2d matrices.

Comment: Here is an [explanation of the COO matrix format](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/coo_matrix.html) with some more examples.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the `coo_matrix()` expects coordinates to be in *2 dimension*: `rows` and `columns`. The `data` values store the actual data values, that is positioned in the *corresponding coordinate*. This is also reflected in the [LightFM.fit()](https://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/lightfm.html#lightfm.LightFM.fit) documentation.

The concept might be unclear, and I'll try to make another explanation than what's given in the documentation: The three inputs *data*, *row*, and *column* must have the same length; and be 1-dimensional.

Each coordinate is typically referred to via the indexes **i** and **j**, row-index and column-index respectively, as they denote the i'th row and j'th column (á la `matrix_row[i]` and `matrix_column[j]`).

Borrowing from the example in [coo_matrix()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) docs:

```
row  = np.array([0, 3, 1, 0])
col  = np.array([0, 3, 1, 2])
data = np.array([4, 5, 7, 9])

for value, i, j in zip(data, row, col):
    print("In the {}'th row, on the {}'th column, insert the value {}"
          .format(i, j, value))
print("All other values are 0, because it's sparse.")

coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4)).toarray()
```

Outputs:

```
In the 0'th row, on the 0'th column, insert the value 4
In the 3'th row, on the 3'th column, insert the value 5
In the 1'th row, on the 1'th column, insert the value 7
In the 0'th row, on the 2'th column, insert the value 9
All other values are 0, because it's sparse.

array([
   [4, 0, 9, 0],
   [0, 7, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 5]
])
```

**Notes on your code:**

The `Error: int object is not subscriptable` error is likely to come from your code, where you try to subscript `k`, which is your *keys*, e.g. your first `k` will be `(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0)`.

When you do `r=int(k[0][1:])` you try get `0[1:]` (because the zero'eth entry in `k` is `0`. Similarily for `c = int(k[1][1:])`, `k[1]` is `1`, so `k[1][1:]` is trying to do `1[1:]`.

Also, doing `int()` would not work. If what you want to do is convert each element in the list, use `numpy.array.astype()`. E.g. `np.array([1.2, 3, 4.4]).astype(int)` will give `array([1, 3, 4])`.